# Glide can not load image without VPN

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I want to show images in recycler View. But Its working when i am using VPN. Without VPN  its now showing any image. Showing SocketTime out Exception. I have tried many ways but its not working. Is there any permanent solution ?

**Code**

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            final Post post=mPost.get(position);
                Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage()).into(holder.post_image);
            if(post.getDescription().equals("")){
                holder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else {
                holder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.description.setText(post.getDescription());

            }
```

**Error  without VPN:-**

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mfree-9290a.appspot.com/o/posts%2F1585227754335.null?alt=media&token=ffbffb6d-b9ed-47bd-9de6-a3e9d478449b with size [480x854]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4007:80f::200a (port 443) from /fec0::25c7:1cfe:a28b:c18 (port 48192) after 2500ms)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4007:80f::200a (port 443) from /fec0::25c7:1cfe:a28b:c18 (port 48192) after 2500ms)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4007:80f::200a (port 443) from /fec0::25c7:1cfe:a28b:c18 (port 48192) after 2500ms)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4007:80f::200a (port 443) from /fec0::25c7:1cfe:a28b:c18 (port 48192) after 2500ms
2020-04-20 11:42:57.350 6981-6981/com.example.mfree I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4007:80f::200a (port 443) from /fec0::25c7:1cfe:a28b:c18 (port 48192) after 2500ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

Comment: Have you tried Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(post.getPostimage()).into(holder.post_image)

Comment: yes. Not working